# Insert spaces around binary operators

Tags: vim, replace

I've statements such as these:

- `someVariable=someOtherVariable`
- `if(oneVariable>otherVariable)`

No spaces around the operators makes it difficult for me to understand the code. I would like to insert spaces around `=` and `>` so that the statements look like these:

- `someVariable = someOtherVariable`
- `if(oneVariable > otherVariable)`

So, basically if there are no spaces around `=` or `>` insert spaces.

How do I achieve this using substitution command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the following command:

```
:%s/\>=\</ = /gc
```

It means: In the entire file (`%`), search for `=` between the end of a word (`\>`) and the beginning of a word (`\<`), and replace it by `=` surrounded by spaces. The `g` flag says: do it on every occurrence in a line, not only on the first one; the `c` flag is for "confirm", which lets you decide on every occurrence if you want to do the change (press `y`) or not (press `n`). If you are sure that you want to replace all hits, you can press `a` or simply omit the `c` flag.

I think you can figure out by yourself how to adjust the command for different binary operators than `=`.